# Adaptec 6405e SATA raid controller + 4x WD Red 1TB .. no Raid 5 option?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

I'm in the ACU/adaptec bios utility.  All four drives are initialized.

I go to Create an Array, select all four drives.  It only gives me Raid 1/10/1EE options - but no RAID 5.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That card doesn't support RAID 5.

From [Adaptec's page for the 6e-series adapters](https://www.adaptec.com/en-us/products/series/6e/):

> - RAID levels 0, 1, 10, 1E, and JBOD

Comment: You know..That makes an amazing amount of sense. I just realized that myself.  I could have sworn it said Raid 5 on the product page when I bought it.  DOH!